# Ubuntu LTS 16.04 upgrade removes my packages?

Tags: 16.04

I am upgrading from the old LTS to the new one. Here's some items in the list of packages that Ubuntu is warning me will be **removed**:

- biber
- grive
- pycharm
- python3.4
- xscreensaver

There's no information on top of this, like "why" and "what does this mean".

Do I have to install them again? **Can** I install them again? Besides xscreensaver, the others are programs that appear to me not directly connected to the operating system. **Why** are they being removed?

Comment: For `biber`, see also http://askubuntu.com/questions/761985/textlive-bibtex-extra-and-biber-conflict

Answer (score 3):

These packages are updated in the new release.

**Biber** new version : 2.3.1 (old 1.6.x )

**Python** new version : 3.5 (old  3.4 or less )

**Grive**: you need to install again.

**Pycharm** : also need to install again.

And of course **xscreensaver** is updated in 16.04 LTS.

The other reason of the update maybe that some dependencies are updated with the new release.
Reply what happens.

Comment: That's why I'm surprised, the packages are not listed under update, rather under removed. So far I'm not sure whether I want to go through with the upgrade...

Comment: Did you use PyCharm community version ?

Comment: No, the education versoin

Comment: only probable reason maybe due to update of python itself. If you try, please let us know. Thanks

Comment: The `biber` version has been badly broken till now. See http://askubuntu.com/a/792631/16395

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all these packages were indeed removed and needed to be reinstalled again.

- Biber: Was not installed with Ubuntu.

> $ biber
>   The program 'biber' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
>   sudo apt install biber

- Pycharm: I was not using the automatically installed package from apt-get, but rather the newer version (which I had stored in `/opt`). Why that independent package had to be removed is unclear to me, but I could reinstall it without problems.
- Grive: I had to reinstall that manually again
- xscreensaver: Also was not installed with the update, had to install it again.